# Ninject problem binding to constant value in MVC3 with a RavenDB session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, ravendb

I've seen a lot of different ways of configuring Ninject with ASP.NET MVC, but the implementation seems to change slightly with each release of the MVC framework. I'm trying to inject a RavenDB session into my repository. Here is what I have that's almost working.

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    ...

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarted();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return new StandardKernel(new MyNinjectModule());
    }

    public static IDocumentSession CurrentSession
    {
        get { return (IDocumentSession)HttpContext.Current.Items[RavenSessionKey]; }
    }
    ...
}

public class MyNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();
        Bind<IDocumentSession>().ToConstant(MvcApplication.CurrentSession);
    }
}
```

When it tries to resolve IDocumentSession, I get the following error.

```
Error activating IDocumentSession using binding from IDocumentSession to constant value
Provider returned null.
Activation path:
  3) Injection of dependency IDocumentSession into parameter documentSession of constructor of type UserRepository
```

Any ideas on how to make the IDocumentSession resolve?

Comment: Random guessing, having not used Ninject - but is your CurrentSession returning null? (that's what the error message sounds like to me).

Comment: @Will - Yes, it returns null when Ninject tries to load it.  But, if I call the code "MvcApplication.CurrentSession" manually in a controller, it returns the actual session object I'm looking for.

Comment: Then what is actually creating the session and sticking it in the HttpContext? That would appear to be executing after Ninject starts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ToConstant(MvcApplication.CurrentSession)` is evaluated at application start. What you want is delayed evaluation `ToMethod(ctx => MvcApplication.CurrentSession)`

Comment: exactly.  it might work the first time, but once that initial HttpContext unloads, you're now bound to a null object.  using ToMethod will evaluate it every time the scope begins.